# average salary for graduating student based on different major

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

I want to get the average salary for graduating student based on different major

3 tables involve: 
Survey_result (Student_Id, Annual_Salary)
Student_Degree(Student_ID, Degree_ID)
Degree(Degree_ID,Major_Name)

Survey_Result

- 9320000000, $1000
- 9320000001, $2000
- 9320000002, $3000
- 9320000003, $4000

Student_Degree

- 9320000000, 1
- 9320000001, 2
- 9320000002, 3
- 9320000003, 4
  Degree
- 1, Accounting
- 2, Finance
- 3, Accounting
- 4, Finance

need sql result: Account: 2000, Finance: 3000

Comment: You should post what did you try...(pls read tour stackoverflow)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this:

```
SELECT
    AVG(Survey_Result.Annual_Salary),
    Degree.Major_Name
FROM
    Degree
    JOIN Student_Degree
        ON Student_Degree.Degree_ID=Degree.Degree_ID
    JOIN Survey_Result
        ON Student_Degree.Student_ID=Survey_Result.Student_ID
GROUP BY
    Degree.Major_Name
```